How to extract custom metadata from pdfdocument using library pdf-lib in javascript
I am using javascript library 'pdf-lib' for extracting metadata from pdf.It is working fine.But it is only able to extract the important metadata.Suppose my pdf having custom metadata like "CUSTOMKEY" and value "1234" it is not able to extract that customkey.(already I have added and commented in line 35).I am getting error.Is there any option to extract custom metadata using this library? Demo link - https://jsfiddle.net/1L65h70f/
HTML
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib@1.5.0"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>Click the button to read a PDF document's metadata with <code>pdf-lib</code></p>
    <button onclick="readPdfMetadata()">Read PDF Metadata</button>
    <ul id="metadata-list"></ul>
  </body>
</html>

Javascript
<script>
    const { PDFDocument } = PDFLib

    async function readPdfMetadata() {
        // Fetch PDF
      const pdfUrl = 'https://pdf-lib.js.org/assets/with_cropbox.pdf';
      const pdfBytes = await fetch(pdfUrl).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());

      // Load the PDF document without updating its existing metadata
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes, { 
        updateMetadata: false 
      })

            // Read all available metadata fields      
      const title = pdfDoc.getTitle();
      const author = pdfDoc.getAuthor();
      const subject = pdfDoc.getSubject();
      const creator = pdfDoc.getCreator();
      const keywords = pdfDoc.getKeywords();
      const producer = pdfDoc.getProducer();
      const creationDate = pdfDoc.getCreationDate();
      const modificationDate = pdfDoc.getModificationDate();
   //   const customkey = pdfDoc.getCustomKey();
      
            // Display all available metadata fields   
      document.getElementById('metadata-list').innerHTML = `
        <li>
          Document: <a href="${pdfUrl}" target="_blank">${pdfUrl}</a>
        </li>
        <li>Title: ${title}</li>
        <li>Author: ${author}</li>
        <li>Creator: ${creator}</li>
        <li>Keywords: ${keywords}</li>
        <li>Producer: ${producer}</li>
        <li>Creation Date: ${creationDate.toISOString()}</li>
        <li>Modification Date: ${modificationDate.toISOString()}</li>
      `;
    }
  </script>


I had a same issue I have used pdf-parse library to extract metadata. Although is done using expressJS to create an api which will extract metadata and from angular using HTTP CLIENT MODULE you can retrive the data.
Here in the above code metadata is a class with specific properties so that cannot be modified to get custom metadata
HOPE IT HELPS THANKS!!!
